# How to control multiple processes based on user defined conditions continuously

Tags: process, cron, ipc

My question involves two programs (kodi and xscreensaver).  Since I have encountered this with other applications, let me be more general and say I have two applications, say App1 and App2.  I wish for App2 to run continuously from startup to shutdown, but often I use App1 while I'm at the computer.  I even sometimes forget to close App1 if I step away.  I wish for App2 to run with it's default setup if App1 is not running. If App1 is running, then I wish for App2 to change it's behavior, but if App1 has been running for a long time (say an hour and a half) then App2 should resume with it's normal setup.

I figured that I could accomplish this with a bash script and something else like perhaps cron or start-stop-daemon.  Here is what I've done so far in bash, in a file named Action_Needed.sh:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Determine if App1 and App2 are running at the same time
    # Exit with 0 if yes, Exit with 1 if not

    ps -e | grep -q "App1"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        # App2 should always be running, but check
        # anyway.  This could potentially be used
        # to restart App2 automatically, if for some
        # reason it was closed or crashed.
        ps -e | grep -q "App2"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
    fi
    else
        return 1
    fi
```

It's simple enough to use this script together with Cron to execute every minute or so and change the behavior of App2 whenever the above script exits with status 0.

What should I do in the situation where App1 is running, and has been for a long time (say an hour and half) and I wish for App2 to continue to run as normal?  Should I use something other than Cron?

Comment: 1st google hit: https://github.com/graysky2/kodi-prevent-xscreensaver

Comment: Thanks for the link.  As I said, I've encountered this issue with other applications...hence would like to see how to handle it in a general case.

Comment: It's very hard job to expand this statement: `if [[ -n $(pidof kodi.bin) ]]; then`...

Comment: True, and honestly Graysky's bash script isn't much different from what I have above, except he did not call grep.  I'll update my comment in a moment.

Yet, there should be some way to do some task and check to see how long that task has been running.  That's really the only issue I have in the problem I describe.

Comment: `xscreensaver` needs to run in the X Windows context and have `DISPLAY` defined in its environment.

Comment: It's better to write a mini shellscript to run kodi. `xscreensaver-command -deactivate; kodi;xscreensaver-command -activate`, and run this if you wanna run kodi.

Comment: I might suggest editing that title a bit, since you know the conditions you're looking for, and they seem to be the main point of the question.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I edited the title.  Hopefully, it makes it more clear.

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I gather you want to check a process with a given name, and do some choice based on if it's running or not, and how long it has been running?

To find the process ID of the process, you could grep the output of `ps`, or use `pidof` as in the example linked in the comments, or similarly, use `pgrep`. Whichever your system has. (e.g. `pgrep` is in the `procps` package on Debian.)

The other thing you wanted, is the time the target program has been running. On recent-ish Linux systems, you can use `ps --no-headers -oetimes $PID` to get the time in seconds since the process was started.

So, something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
target="App1"   
# target=$1  # uncoment to take the target from the command line
pid=$(pgrep --oldest "$target")  
if [ -n "$pid" ] ; then
    time=$(ps --no-headers -oetimes "$pid")
    echo "Oldest $target has been running for $time seconds"
    if [ "$time" -gt 5400 ] ; then
        echo "That's more than 1.5 hours"
    fi
fi
```

Though note that `pgrep` (and `pidof`) will happily return more than one PID if the search matches more than one process. You'll have to deal with that somehow, either by making the match narrow enough (`pgrep -f` can be useful here), picking the `--newest` or `--oldest` with `pgrep`, or modifying the script to only take one of the PID's output by the program.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use *sh for advanced process control.
By nature, that disqualifies SysVinit too.
You can always mend-and-append an init script through every painful edge case failure until it seems to *always* work right, and then remain responsible for it until the next one comes up.

systemd supports jobs w/dependencies and so does upstart.
Both also have "user session" modes for running user GUIs like this.

Comment: Can you show an example as to how to check with systemd (or upstart) how long a process has been running?

Comment: `initctl status <job>` (upstart) just shows the PID but `systemctl status <job>` will show lots of info.

I'm not biased toward PID 1, you can pick from a bunch of other supervisors too. The point is to not handle this in one-shot scripts + cron, unless you really just want to play bash golf forever.